# Sublime - in each line delete text before and after specific WORD

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a million lines text that looks like:

```
HELLO random1 WORLD
HELLO random2 WORLD
HELLO random3 WORLD
```

How with the tools [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) provide, I can extract only the text that I need so the result would be:

```
random1 
random2 
random3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search using regex, with this parameter `HELLO (\w+) WORLD` and replace it with `\1` (or `$1`)

the \w is regex for a word. And the brackets around it capture it and assign it to the variable $1

Comment: Worked beautifully when I tested in my Sublime-- but note it probably needs to be `HELLO (\w+) WORLD` not `HELLO (\w) WORLD`.

Comment: oops my bad, that's what I get for not testing my own regex

Answer (score 1):

use regex option in search and replace. This regex, without quotes, will select both words.

```
"HELLO | WORLD"
```

This is probably oversimplified solution. You need to post more realistic examples for us to provide with an exact solution

Comment: He can use a capture group, they can offer him the flexibility he needs